# MediaRecorder, start failed: -19

Tags: android, google-glass, video-recording, google-gdk

Has anyone managed to successfully record a video using MediaRecorder on Glass?

This is the code i am using in order to prepare the Recorder. I keep getting error -19.

```
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    recorder.setOutputFile(videoFile);

    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);

    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

    recorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);

    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
```

Thank you.

**Update**:
It seems to be a GDK bug. I have reported it and it got accepted. If you are having the same issue just star the bug report to stay informed:

https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=360

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start video capture on Glass it seems that you have to completely stop the video preview. If you are using a previewing camera, prior of doing anything with a MediaRecorder, just run:

```
try {
    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
} catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
    Log.d(TAG, "IOException nullifying preview display: " + ioe.getMessage());
}
mCamera.stopPreview();
mCamera.unlock();
```

More info here: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=360#c6

Answer (score 1):

After much frustration and iteration, I'm pleased to report that it IS possible to use MediaRecorder on Glass XE12. The below code works for me on my Glass Version 1 running XE12:

```
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(preview.getHolder().getSurface());
    mCamera.unlock();
    // Step 2: Set sources

    mMediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(new android.media.MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
        public void onError(MediaRecorder mediarecorder1, int k, int i1)
        {
            Log.e(TAG,String.format("Media Recorder error: k=%d, i1=%d", k, i1));
        }

    });
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(0);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(0);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(2);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(2);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(0x4c4b40);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1280, 720);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(2);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(3);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(0x17700);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
    mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(0);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());
    mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(-1);

    // Step 5: Set the preview output
    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        mMediaRecorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Unknown exception preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver! I sent the Glass for replacement with version 2, i will test it as soon as i get it back.

Comment: Unfortunately Olivier it didn't work for me. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When do you prepare the recorder, is it something that happens when you launch your application? If so, are you launching it with a voice trigger?

If both of those things are true, this might be an instance of [the bug described here](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=259). Can you try the workaround in that thread (exponential backoff) and see if it works?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case. I can successfully launch the app (it is an activity, not a live card) and can see a preview of the camera on a Surface. The problem occurs as soon as i try to use the MediaRecorder to record the video.

Thank you for your reply!